# How to subset a vector inside list of list

Tags: r, list

I have the following list of list:

```
foo <- list(a = list(x = 1:10, y = 11:25), b = list(x = 1:10, y = 100:110))
```

It looks like this:

```
> foo
$a
$a$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$a$y
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25


$b
$b$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$b$y
 [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

What I want to do is to only pick first 3 of the list yielding:

```
$a
$a$x
 [1]  1  2  3  

$a$y
 [1] 11 12 13 


$b
$b$x
 [1]  1  2  3  

$b$y
 [1] 100 101 102
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A wild `?rapply` appears:

```
rapply(foo, f=head, n=3, how="list")
#$a
#$a$x
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$a$y
#[1] 11 12 13
#
#
#$b
#$b$x
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$b$y
#[1] 100 101 102
```

This is a `r`ecursive `apply` which will go through each list until a non-list is found and then apply a `f=`unction. The `how="list"` argument just ensures that you get the same `list` structure back again.

Answer (score 4):

Use nested `lapply`

```
lapply(foo, lapply, `[`, 1:3)

#$a
#$a$x
#[1] 1 2 3

#$a$y
#[1] 11 12 13


#$b
#$b$x
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b$y
#[1] 100 101 102
```

Or use `head`

```
lapply(foo, lapply, head, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(purrr)
foo %>% map_depth(2,head,3)
#$a
#$a$x
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$a$y
#[1] 11 12 13
#
#
#$b
#$b$x
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$b$y
#[1] 100 101 102
```